# How to reduce delay between change chanel in Mumudvb?

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video, dvb

I use **mumudvb v1.7** to send channel in http stream. On client side that stream is shown via `<video>` tag and browser supporting HTML5.

Now I have a problem that when I want to change channel, the browser shows a black screen for 3 seconds before showing next http stream. I guess that it's being normal because video tag must change source. One second of those 3 seconds are taken by **mumudvb** on switching stream to a new channel.

Now I want to know if it is possible to change source of video tag faster?

Or is it possible to let **mumudvvb** send http request faster?

Comment: i found someone either have this problem http://45.79.75.140/forum/viewtopic.php?f=156&t=9206

Comment: when i use vlc to show tv channel ...changing chanel is too fast but on html page it take 3 or 4 second...i gusses taht fetching http url in vlc is faster than http...